# Some good color theme for Python in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse

I've switched to Eclipse from Sublime Text 2 and I'm looking for a good color theme which works well with python. Most of them on eclipsecolorthemes.org are horrible and don't handle operators/brackets and other stuff too well.

Any suggestions?